# how to solve unresolve attribute reference objects in pyCharm

Tags: django, pycharm

I'm new to django and I was following a certain tutorial on it using the community Edition of pyCharm but I got this error that says unresolved attribute reference objects for class Product. I haven't missed any steps from the tutorial I followed but I don't really know why I'm getting the error. Please I need help on how to solve it. The error is actually from that place that I have Product.objects().all

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from products.models import Product


def index(request):
    products = Product.objects().all
    return render(request,'index.html',{'products':products})


def new(request):
    return HttpResponse('New Products')


models.py
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)


class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The community edition doesn't have the specific Django support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html) that would enable *Code insight support for Django ORM*.

You'll just have to live with the fact that `objects` looks like it's undefined, or maybe as a band-aid give PyCharm an annotation hint:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

    objects: Manager  # <- this annotation
```